# IndexError: too many indices

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to use an algorithm in scikit-learn to predict the output based on a number of inputs. I seem to be getting the error 'too many indices' returned, but cannot figure out why.

CSV File Training:

```
 1.1    0.2 0.1 0   0.12    0.1
 1.4    0.2 0.1 0.1 0.14    0.1
 0.1    0.1 0.1 0   0.26    0.1
 24.5   0.1 0   0.1 0.14    0.1
 0.1    0.1 0.1 0   0.25    0.1
```

Code:

```
    fileCSVTraining = genfromtxt('TrainingData.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None)

    #Define first 6 rows of data as the features
    t = fileCSVTraining[:, 6:]

    #Define which column to put prediction in
    r = fileCSVTraining[:, 0-6:]    
    #Create and train classifier 
    x, y = r, t
    clf = LinearSVC()
    clf = clf.fit(x, y)     
    #New data to predict
    X_new = [1.0, 2.1, 3.0, 2.4, 2.1]
    b = clf.predict(X_new)
```

Error:

```
 t = fileCSVTraining[:, 6:]
 IndexError: too many indices
```

Comment: I think this error will happen if you try to index a 1D array in two dimensions, not completely sure though

Comment: Maybe not the problem, but you are using `delimiter=','` while reading the file, although the values are separated by spaces

Comment: Seems to be something to do with the decimal points in the CSV file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, I think you want:

```
fileCSVTraining = genfromtxt('TrainingData.csv')
```

Then, to get the "first 6 rows", you would use

```
t = fileCSVTraining[:6, :]
```

(I'm assuming your actual data file is longer than you've shown.  Your example has only 5 rows.)

I suspect your use of array indexing to get `r` is also incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Please print your `x` and `y` variables and you will likely see why the data is invalid and fix accordingly.

Also for the last line:

```
X_new = [1.0, 2.1, 3.0, 2.4, 2.1]
b = clf.predict(X_new)
```

should be:

```
X_new = [[1.0, 2.1, 3.0, 2.4, 2.1]]
b = clf.predict(X_new)
```

as predict expects a collection of samples (2D array of `(n_new_samples, n_features)`), not a single sample.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexing to get r and t was incorrect. Using:

```
  t = fileCSVTraining[:, 1-0:]
```

Got me the required training data, leaving the prediction column.

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to specify dtype=float  because "None" will allow for integers (if there were any in your data) to be included in the array which would force 1-D array instead of a 2-D array. Indexing, as shown, does not work on 1-D.