# Too many indices error, in my already micro dataset

Tags: python, numpy, slice, data-processing

This is my small test CSV file, because I'm trying to isolate the error.

```
Destination Port    Flow Duration   Total Fwd Packets   Labels
22  20  100 BENIGN
21  30  200 BENIGN
43  30  100 Bot
15  11  203 Bot
```

So when I run the following code, to preprocess the data,

```
import csv
# import itertools
import os
from os.path import join as os_join
import numpy as np


dataroot = r'D:\DDOS\testing_too_many_indices'

attacks = {'BENIGN': 0, 'Bot': 1}
# and many others

features = ['Destination Port', 'Flow Duration', 'Total Fwd Packets']

np.random.seed(1202)


def get_filenames(a_dir):
    return [name for name in os.listdir(a_dir)
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(a_dir, name))]


def read_csv(filename, sampling_rate=100):
    with open(filename) as csv_file:
        print('Reading {} ...'.format(filename))
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        # header = next(reader)
        data = [row for row in reader]
        print('#{} rows read'.format(len(data)))
        N = len(data)
        sample_size = N*sampling_rate//100
        indices = np.random.randint(0, N, sample_size)
        sampled_data = [data[i] for i in indices]
    return sampled_data


def read_data(dataroot, sampling_rate=10, seed=0):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    filenames = get_filenames(dataroot)
    data = []
    for filename in filenames:
        data_part = read_csv(os_join(dataroot, filename), sampling_rate)
        data += data_part
    return data


data = read_data(dataroot, sampling_rate=10)

arr = np.array(data)
# X contains feature values and Y the output values.
X = arr[:, :-1].astype(np.float32)  # ERROR HERE.
Y_str = arr[:, -1]
```

I get the error as follows:-

```
File "/some_path/temp.py", line 63, in <module>
    X = arr[:, :-1].astype(np.float32)

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

What should I do? I've wracked my brains on other possibly duplicate links like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163047/python-too-many-indices-for-array?rq=1), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793585/indexerror-too-many-indices), etc. Also made the above sample snippet to test in isolation, read about [2D slicing](https://machinelearningmastery.com/index-slice-reshape-numpy-arrays-machine-learning-python/) and yet am clueless. Can you help me?

Comment: That you `arr[:, :-1]` have `shape (3,)` (`arr[:, :-1].shape`). You don't have two demensional. You can only take `arr[:-1]`.

Comment: You are assuming `arr` is a 2d array. Don't assume.  Verify.  Check shape, and dtype. if 1d object dtype, check elements.